# Combination of multiple lists using formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have already asked a very similar [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/683789/comparison-of-accounts-in-excel-windows-7-between-two-different-sheets-and-combi#683789), but I now want to do it automatically (using functions etc).

I'm an accountant and have two different sheets of different and/or the same accounts. I need from all those combine one total list (some are in both but some accounts only in one). **But I want to do it with vlookup and if functions (combine both)**. currently they look like this:

```
sheet 1:                                         sheet2:  
51100 Employee Salaries                          41000 Purchase of Services 
51100 Employee Salaries Total                    41000 Purchase of Services Total
51110 Employee Salaries, Accrual                 51100 Employee Salaries 
51110 Employee Salaries, Accrual Total           51110 Employee Salaries, Accrual Total
52100 Overtime Pay
52100 Overtime Pay Total
```

I would like to combine them but not have duplicates. So, to join then 2 together would give:

```
41000 Purchase of Services 
41000 Purchase of Services Total
51100 Employee Salaries 
51100 Employee Salaries //should not exist as it's a duplicate                         
51100 Employee Salaries Total                    
51110 Employee Salaries, Accrual                 
51110 Employee Salaries, Accrual Total           
51110 Employee Salaries, Accrual Total //should not exist as it's a duplicate
52100 Overtime Pay
52100 Overtime Pay Total
```

can I somehow combine "vlookup" for this and "if" functions-say, do vlookup in each sheet (next column);appears #N/A (means that in sheet1 such record/account doesn't exist) and afterwards insert if funtion in sheet1 where determine: if in cell is #N/A, write account from column in front, if vlokup found something - write vlookup data. And how afterwards can I combine this or do the some solution to have what I want  **but using formulas**?

currently I use

```
=IF((VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$49;1;FALSE))=FALSE;A2;(VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$49;1;FALSE)))
```

but false for if doesn't work. Note instead of sheet1 & sheet2 I have sheet2 & sheet3 in formula

Comment: yes, since in it also fits name from accounts that can be vlookuped

Comment: Yes, your syntax is incorrect. Are you trying to right `if firstLookUp) = false then show A2` ?

Comment: yes - the first vlookup ir for vlookuping the name of account and if it's equal to false or shows #N/a (finds no such account in second sheet) then I want to see A2. If account is vlookuped and found also in other sheet - then I want to be showed the vlookuped account name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you've provided could be written as follows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$49;1;FALSE);A2)
```

Or like this for 2003 and earlier users (as IFERROR was introduced in 2007):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$49;1;FALSE));A2;
    VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$49;1;FALSE))
```

**EDIT**
The easiest way to create a list containing all unique items from sheets 1 and 2 is to add all the rows from sheet 2 underneath the rows from sheet 1 and then use Remove Duplicates in the Data tab to stip out the duplicate rows.

If you record a macro that does this you can get some starter code to build a solid macro to help make this dynamic moving forward.

Comment: Although I didn't get out combination by using these formulas (it just allowed to get the same list of accounts from 1st column) of one list from two sheets - then better comparison was with #N/A where I at least identified accounts which are not in each sheet

Comment: yes - it does help in seeing the math or mismatch but my aim is also to combine a list of accounts in one sheet BUT using formulas (obviously I'm not using the right ones) and avoiding duplicates as shown above

Comment: The easiest way to do it though (and you may be able to build a macro that uses this) is to add all the rows from sheet 2 underneath the rows from sheet 1 and then use Remove Duplicates in the Data tab to stip out the duplicate rows

Comment: yes - thanks!!! this means that the first suggested solution was the best (easiest) and I overload myself with unnecesary formulas that give nothing!

Comment: No worries, it happens all the time (I know it happens to me all the time in any case)  :)